# Locate shop with a particular item in android

Tags: android

In my application, there will be a list of item when the users pick a particular item, google map will display the possible shops where user can buy that item. 
Basically, I know about how to deal with google map api, however I dont really clear about how to get the real item then target it to the real shop. Could anyone suggest me some ways to do that ? Thanks

By the way, are there some applications like that on the google play ??

Answer (score 0):

may be you are interested in [google places](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/places/) api...